# Find specific byte combination inside NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

We found out that we have a bunch of french strings with incorrect characters.
We know that the hexadecimal representation of the character is 0xFDFF.
Is there an easy way to SELECT the rows in a table where the NVarchar field contain this character?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help Arthur, +1 for you.
I ended up creating a cursor and checking all characters in every row of the table to find the  strange 0xFDFF character. I concatenated all ids into a variable and got my list from there.

```
DECLARE CURSOR ...
....
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

        Declare @pos int
        set @Pos = 0

        while @Pos <= Len(@Str)
        begin
            if(convert(binary(2), substring(@Str, @pos, 1), 0) = 0xFDFF)
            begin
                set @ids = @ids + ',' + cast(@TheId as varchar)
                --Select @TheId, @Str
                break
            end
            set @Pos = @Pos + 1
        end

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TheId, @Str   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select @ids
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WRONG: select * from YourTable where YourCol like '%' + CONVERT(nchar, 0xFDFF) + '%'
```

EDIT:
oops, (n)char(x) pitfall

```
right: select * from sys.sysobjects where name like '%' + CONVERT(nchar(1), 0x4800) + '%'
```

EDIT2:

```
select * from sys.sysobjects where charindex(CONVERT(nvarchar(1), 0xFDFF), name) > 0
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work. Probably because this character is not a normal one.

Comment: select CONVERT(nchar, 0xFDFF) returns a character. What is the problem? No Results? Or a Syntax Error?

Comment: No results, and I know at least 2 rows that have this character. I see it when I select convert(binary, FieldName, 1).

Comment: MAd a mistake, (n)char(x) pitfall

Comment: Now I get all rows in the table... Very strange.

Comment: CONVERT(nchar(1), 0x4800) == 'H'?

Comment: I think I need to do a binary search on the string to find it, if TSQL can't do this we2ll end up creating a consola app for this..

Comment: @Arthur, yes 0x4800 is 'H' but I think the "like" operator doesn't like the character 0xFDFF... :P

Comment: Just try it with your query and FDFF
select * from sys.sysobjects where name like '%' + CONVERT(nchar(1), 0xFDFF) + '%'

Comment: What about this: select * from sys.sysobjects where charindex(CONVERT(nvarchar(1), 0xFDFF), name) > 0

Comment: Hmm, actually it brings some rows, but not all... I'm checking better.

Comment: It only brings the rows that start with that character! Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I still did not find an accurate solution for finding 0xFDFF invalid character inside nvarchar column. Finally this should work in most, if not all, cases:

```
CHARINDEX('FDFF',CONVERT(varchar(max),(CAST(fname AS VARBINARY(max))),2)) > 0
```